# Is javassist version 3.24.0.GA compatible with java 8?

Tags: java-8, javassist

I am currently on JDK 1.8. I am using javassist-3.18.1.GA.jar and I want to upgrade to 3.24.0.GA. I would like to know if javassist-3.24.0.GA is compatible with JDK 1.8 or not.

If not, then which version of javassist can be used that is compatible to JDK 1.8?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the javaassist-3.24.0.GA.zip then check the Readme.html file inside.
It has instructions on how to compile and run test classes(ex:- sample/Test.java) using your JDK.

You just have to run the below commands in command-line to compile and run Test class to check compatibility to JDK 1.8 when you are in the folder where Readme.html is located.

```
>javac -cp .;javassist.jar sample/Test.java
>java -cp .;javassist.jar sample.Test
```

There are multiple test classes available in sample folder for you to test javassist features.